# Background worker repeats itself

Tags: c#, listview, backgroundworker

Running into another problem with my code.

Scenario:

I use a background worker to populate a listView with data from an XML file. Everything works fine, however when I populate the listView using the background worker it repeats itself over and over, usually 3 - 5 times. Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace THC_Poker_Notifier
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int FPPFee = 0;
        string StartDate;

        // Control Invike functions for multi-threading

        delegate void UniversalVoidDelegate();

        public static void ControlInvike(Control control, Action function)
        {
            if (control.IsDisposed || control.Disposing)
                return;

            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(new UniversalVoidDelegate(() => ControlInvike(control, function)));
                return;
            }
            function();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void supportThisProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SupportProject donate = new SupportProject();
            donate.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }

        private void LoadAllTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView1, () => listView1.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("https://www.pokerstars.com/datafeed/tournaments/all.xml");

            ListViewItem item;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                DateTimeOffset startDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact((string)dr["start_date"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

                TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.StandardName.ToString());
                DateTimeOffset converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startDate, tz);

                if (dr["play_money"].ToString() != "true")
                {

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee == 0)
                    {

                        if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                        {

                            item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), converted.ToString("d"), converted.ToString("t"), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                            ControlInvike(listView1, () => listView1.Items.Add(item));
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void LoadRegularTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView2, () => listView2.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/regular.xml");

            ListViewItem item2;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee == 0)
                    {

                        if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                        {

                            item2 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                            ControlInvike(listView2, () => listView2.Items.Add(item2));


                        }

                    }

            }

        }

        private void LoadSatelliteTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView3, () => listView3.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/satellite.xml");

            ListViewItem item3;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee == 0)
                    {

                        if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                        {

                            item3 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                            ControlInvike(listView3, () => listView3.Items.Add(item3));


                        }

                    }

            }

        }

        private void LoadSpecialTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView4, () => listView4.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/special.xml");

            ListViewItem item4;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                if (FPPFee == 0)
                {

                    if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                    {

                        item4 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                        ControlInvike(listView4, () => listView4.Items.Add(item4));


                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void LoadFreerollTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView5, () => listView5.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/freeroll.xml");

            ListViewItem item5;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                if (dr["play_money"].ToString() != "true")
                {

                    StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee == 0)
                    {

                        if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                        {

                            item5 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                            ControlInvike(listView5, () => listView5.Items.Add(item5));


                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void LoadFPPTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView6, () => listView6.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/all.xml");

            ListViewItem item6;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                if (dr["play_money"].ToString() != "true")
                {

                    StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee != 0)
                    {

                        item6 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                        ControlInvike(listView6, () => listView6.Items.Add(item6));


                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void LoadPlayMoneyTournaments()
        {

            ControlInvike(listView7, () => listView7.Items.Clear());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/freeroll.xml");

            ListViewItem item7;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
            {

                if (dr["play_money"].ToString() == "true")
                {

                    StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

                    FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                    if (FPPFee == 0)
                    {

                        item7 = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString() });
                        ControlInvike(listView7, () => listView7.Items.Add(item7));


                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void timerUpdateGames_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }

        private void pictureBox3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            LoadAllTournaments();
            LoadRegularTournaments();
            LoadSatelliteTournaments();
            LoadSpecialTournaments();
            LoadFreerollTournaments();
            LoadFPPTournaments();
            LoadPlayMoneyTournaments();

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
            }

            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }

            else
            {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the listView would be populated more than once? I wouldn't mind, however it removes the items while it's updating so I cannot access the list for several minutes.

Comment: Maybe it's something in one of the other methods that you didn't show: `LoadRegularTournaments`, `LoadSatelliteTournaments`, etc...  Are you sure those aren't populating the same list?

Comment: Hi, the other methods are exactly the same as LoadAllTournaments but just different XML sources for different games (and updating a different listView which are accessed from other tabs). Thanks

Comment: Without seeing all your code, it's not going to be possible to tell what's going on.  Maybe you made a typo in the other code, for instance.

Comment: The easiest way to see why it is repeating itself it is to debug it. Learn to do this. So put a break point in the start of the method execute the worker once. If the break point was hit twice check the call stack on second hit and you will see it why. Learn to debug properly it will save you a lot of time !

Comment: No, don't do that.  Add it to your question.

Comment: OK added full code to question. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal example which reproduces the behavior, nobody is going to appreciate reading a wall of code. That aside, from a brief glance it looks like you are hooking the event handlers to the BGW events more than once - don't do that. Do it once, then just run it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what's going on from what you have provided, but one thing that caught my eye is you are calling `RunWorkerAsync` again from the `timerUpdateGames_Tick` method.  I couldn't find any `timerUpdateGames`...is that somewhere else?  Do you have a timer that is running and causing your bg worker to run over and over again?

Also, your code is very wet (as in, not [D.R.Y](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjNlr_RofTIAhXCKCYKHV2mD4g&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDon%27t_repeat_yourself&usg=AFQjCNH27hysufwHVMAVfZEp4cSFurM2uQ&sig2=BjpDwHBLDKh-TZqL2c8Auw&bvm=bv.106379543,d.eWE)).  Consider refactoring it so the repeated code -- the code that is in each of the methods that load tournament data -- is in one method that takes parameters for the things that are different.  This will reduce a lot of errors and make your code much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes I will be adding parameters to one universal function when I do a final cleanup, i.e adding a URL parameter for the XML file, however I do need to update different listView's based on what URL is used but I guess I could add IF statements. timerUpdateGames is a timer that updates every 60 seconds auto enabled at runtime.

Comment: @user3733885 Don't put an if statement in your universal function -- pass the appropriate list view as a parameter.

Comment: OK I will keep that in mind, the code is still not clean as I've only been working on it around 3 hours total so far, so as soon as everything works as it should I will clean everything up.

Comment: In the future, you should consider starting off working with a universal function.  As soon as you need to do something twice, put it in its own method.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found my problem. I removed the following and it seems to work fine:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```